# MySQL JOIN with WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT t1.`id`, t1.`vehicle`, lp1.`veh_no` AS `lp_vehicle`, 
          t1.`last_date`, t1.`due_date`, t1.`driver`, lp4.`employ_name` AS `lp_driver`
   FROM `inspection` AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN `vehicle` AS lp1 
     ON (t1.`vehicle` = lp1.`id`) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `employee_driver` AS lp4 
     ON (t1.`driver` = lp4.`id`)) subq,
WHERE MONTH(t1.`due_date`) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
ORDER by vehicle asc;
```

It processes through fine until I get to the WHERE clause.

This is what I get on the above:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
  'WHERE MONTH(t1.`due_date`) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
   ORDER b' 
at line 1
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? I'm running MySQL 5.1.48

Answer (score 6):

you have an extra comma after subq